# Is grunt-vulcanize compatible with vulcanize 1.8.1?

Tags: polymer-1.0

I'm starting to experiment with Polymer 1.0 and am having issues with the vulcanize process. I have included a separate html file for all of my component imports that is loaded via an import in index.html. This site is currently a single page with a paper-drawer-panel a couple of paper-header-panels (drawer and main) with paper-toolbars inside them. This all works perfectly before I vulcanize the site. Once I vulcanize the site the paper-drawer-panel renders the "main" section above the "drawer" section no matter the screen size.

**Before Vulcanize (drawer opened)**

[image]

**After Vulcanize**

[image]

I've done some investigation and [this page](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration.html#vulcanize) states that vulcanize versions 1.0+ are for Polymer version 0.8+. The current version of vulcanize is 1.8.1 so I'm assuming that works for Polymer 1.0. Now, when I install grunt-vulcanize that includes vulcanize 0.7.9 which according to the documentation is not compatible with Polymer 1.0. Here is the output from npm list:

```
npm list -g vulcanize
/usr/local/lib
├─┬ grunt-vulcanize@0.6.4
│ └── vulcanize@0.7.9 
└── vulcanize@1.8.1
```

So how do I get grunt-vulcanize to use vulcanize 1.8.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after little search I found that issue on that was opened 5 days ago

https://github.com/Polymer/grunt-vulcanize/issues/21

one github user leave comment that he made temporary adaptation for grunt-vulcanize which works with vulcanize 1.8.1 and Polymer 1.0. I hope it will help
https://github.com/kgadzinowski/grunt-vulcanize/

Comment: just change in package.json "grunt-vulcanize": "kgadzinowski/grunt-vulcanize" 

it'll work fine

Answer (score 1):

grunt-vulcanize is not compatible with vulcanize 1.8.1, because last update on github was on Feb 9 with version 0.6.4. It's out of date plugin for Polymer 0.8+. I've met  same issue in my grunt project with Polymer 1.0 today and I didn't find how to vulcanize polymer elements in grunt project

grunt-vulcanize on github https://github.com/Polymer/grunt-vulcanize